# Can I set the compile library path used by npm in 'npm install'?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have an application that runs using node.js - in order to run down a particular bug, I have a custom version of node (not the system default install) that I want to run my application with.  So in my start script I change:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

to

```
#!/Users/cmlacy/Dropbox/Engine/code/node-v0.8.9/out/Release/node
```

When I run the application, I get a series of errors that I don't get before the change:

```
crispin:node cmlacy$ ./engine.js 
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN2v816FunctionTemplate3NewEPFNS_6HandleINS_5ValueEEERKNS_9ArgumentsEES3_NS1_INS_9SignatureEEE
  Referenced from: /Users/cmlacy/Dropbox/Engine/code/Engine-Developer/node/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/build/Release/bson.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN2v816FunctionTemplate3NewEPFNS_6HandleINS_5ValueEEERKNS_9ArgumentsEES3_NS1_INS_9SignatureEEE
  Referenced from: /Users/cmlacy/Dropbox/Engine/code/Engine-Developer/node/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/build/Release/bson.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I'm assuming that this is because some of the dependencies in node_modules have been compiled against the wrong node libraries - how do I go about changing the version of node that is included in compilation during an `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your specific node version is in the path before the system node in your shells. That should do it (and of course clean out any old node_modules build directories).